# caffe copy pretrained weights to train a network which supports for larger input

Tags: caffe, matcaffe

How can I use the pretrained e.g. AlexNet model to train a CNN which supports larger (e.g. 500x500) input image sizes?

In other words, how to copy only the convolutional filters to the new network (using Matlab wrapper)?

Comment: even if you copy the weights of the conv layers, you still have to train from scratch the weights for the `"InnerProduct"` layers.

Comment: Thats true. I found a way but not sure thats the correct way. I just use the same name for the convolutional layers and used a different name (compared to the alexnet prototxt file) for the FC layers and copied the weights using the solver.net.copy_from(weightsFN);. It seems work.

Comment: it's the most straight-forward way. you can post it as an answer.

Comment: But if I want to copy this for different nets (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226378/how-to-create-this-cnn-architecture-in-caffe?noredirect=1#comment63891207_38226378 ) I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: ahh... the duplication part is a bit tricky, if you do not want to link them like in a Siamese network...  It can be easily done using python interface. google "caffe net surgery".

Comment: Thanks alot. I am looking for matlab. Anyway i will go through "Siamese network".

Comment: are you fully aware of the difference between initializing the two paths to the same weights, and fixing the weights to be identical?

Comment: Yes. But not sure in the implementation point of view (how to make the two paths to be identical or different). In my case i would like to initialize with a pretrained model, but the two paths can be identical as well.

Comment: But if I want to have two different networks what can i do?

Comment: "net surgery" sounds like the easiest way. If you are going to work with caffe, the python interface is much more evolved than the matlab interface. You should not fear learning some python. it's not too difficult.